# Why doesn't the compiler allow this?

Tags: java

since I desperately search for a solution for 3 hours, but didn't find anything, I'm gonna try it here.

```
    public static void Assemble(boolean isAnnuityLoan, double K, double P, int N) {

    double loan = K;
    int year = 1;

    Output.PrintHeader();

    if (isAnnuityLoan) {
        double *rpy* = Calculation.AnnRatePerYear(K, P, N);
    } else {
        double *T* = Calculation.AmortRate(N, K);
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < N; x++) {

        double I = Calculation.Interest(loan, P);

        if (isAnnuityLoan) {
            double T = Calculation.AnnAmortRate(**rpy**, loan, P);
        } else {
            double rpy = Calculation.RatePerYear(loan, P, **T**);
        }

        Output.PrintTableLine(year, loan, I, **T**, **rpy**);
        loan = loan - **T**;
        year++;

        System.out.println("\n");
    }
```

Thats the code. Oh cool looks like formatting doesnt work in the code segment. Anyway, problem is, compiler marks the italic variables (*K* and *rpy*) as not used, and the bold ones (double stars) as not found. Now this doesnt make any sense to me, because lets trace both paths.

1. isAnnuityLoan is false. itll calculate T, then enter the for loop and since isAnnuityLoan is still false, the else statement will trigger and rpy will be calculated.
2. is vice versa, rpy gets calculated first, the T in the loop, and therefore both variables should be available.

Buuuut theyre not. And I have no idea why. Now where is the issue with this?

You help is highly apprechiated and will help me not to riddle about this in my sleep.

Comment: Because `rpy` is only available inside the if statements where you declared it. Same for `T`.

Comment: You have **local** variables defined inside their respective blocks - they are not aware of each other existence.

Comment: Basically, you need to research variable *scope*.

Comment: `Java` is not `JavaScript`, baby!!!

Comment: makes sense. But how do I fix this? I could make it public, but is that the best solution? Edit: why cant I make it public? (not allowed either)

Comment: problem is they have to stay in the for loop. And I only need either function. Sure I could make 2 loops but there has to be an easier solution. I feel like I'm missing something big here

Comment: @CrystalRain Move their declaration (`double rpy, T;`) before any `if` or `for` statements. As Jon is saying, they way they're declared in your code, they're only available to the local scope (in between their `{...}` block). And make sure to only define them once.

Comment: tried that already, produces error variables might not have been initialized.  I need to get them out of the scope of the if statement

Comment: Then define them with a default value. `double rpy=0.0, T=0.0;` Your error is either the compiler realising that you might not enter the `for` loop so one of the variables will not be initialised, or just a mistake.

Comment: solved it. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- "rpy" variable is defined inside an if scope, so you can't it outside.
- To use variables outside if scope, take a look at the example below.
- Note that warnings are different than errors. Compiler WILL compile your code even if it contains warnings like (variable not used) but NOT errors.

example :

```
//define var
int x;
if(test){
//initialize it here
    x = 1;
} else {
//or here
    x = 2;
}
//use it here
System.out.println(x);
```

Comment: OP was using the asterisks to put variables in italic or bold, not realising they weren't displayed inside a code block. They are irrelevant to the question.